# SQL Server - Efficient way to create a mapping / conglomeration of my data

Tags: sql-server, dictionary, join

Suppose I have the following table in SQL Server (2012):

```
MyTable:
Col1:    Col2:    Col3:   Col4:    Val1:   ...   Valn:
a        b        c       d        123           1234
....
```

And I'm looking to create a mapping table that would map, for specific values in `Col1` - `Col4` to a specific label. So, for example, it could look as follows:

```
MyMaps:
Col1:    Col2:    Col3:    Col4:    Label:
a        <null>   <null>   d        Label1
<null>   b        <null>   d        Label2
```

Where, for example, the first row could be read as:
**Give the label 'Label1' to any row in MyTable where `Col1`='a' and `Col4` = 'd'**.

So, the query I've created which can allow for this mapping is:

```
SELECT
   MyMaps.Label
   ,MyTable.Val1
    ...
   ,MyTable.Valn
FROM
   MyTable
   INNER JOIN MyMaps
   ON ISNULL(MyTable.Col1, '') = COALESCE(MyMaps.Col1, MyTable.Col1, '')
   AND ISNULL(MyTable.Col2, '') = COALESCE(MyMaps.Col2, MyTable.Col2, '')
   AND ISNULL(MyTable.Col3, '') = COALESCE(MyMaps.Col3, MyTable.Col3, '')
   AND ISNULL(MyTable.Col4, '') = COALESCE(MyMaps.Col4, MyTable.Col4, '')
```

And it works, but I'm curious if this is a good way to accomplish this or if there is a better / more efficient way of creating a mapping since MyTable is a fairly large table.

Any thoughts / suggestions?

Comment: since MyTable has cols ABCD, what happen if MyMaps contain (null, b,c, null) Label3? which is a match and so is Label1. how do you pick the correct label? Also, based on your join condition, it won't perform well on a large table since you're using COALESCE and ISNULL.

Comment: What would happen if 2 maps found for one row of `MyTable` table?

Comment: @KMC & Siyavash, good point. I just have no clue how else to do this and, given my data, I'm assuming it won't be the case.... I just truly don't have any clue how else to accomplish this kind of mapping.

Comment: @JohnBustos your query matches both rows in your example, is that what you want? If not what criteria would you use to determine to map against Label1 rather than Label2 or vice versa?

Comment: @SteveFord, as I said before, I don't really have a better way to create this mapping table. I have created separate queries to check for duplicate mappings after the fact, but this is the only way I could think of to create the mapping I needed. I'm VERY open to different architectures, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it such as selecting the first match or using complex joins or writing complex TSQL with loops and etc. For ex)

```
  SELECT

           t.*,
           Label = ( 
                    --since there can be multiple matches, this is where you apply your rules
                     select top 1 label
                     from  MyMaps
                     where ISNULL(MyTable.Col1, '') = COALESCE(MyMaps.Col1, MyTable.Col1, '')
                       AND ISNULL(MyTable.Col2, '') = COALESCE(MyMaps.Col2, MyTable.Col2, '')
                       AND ISNULL(MyTable.Col3, '') = COALESCE(MyMaps.Col3, MyTable.Col3, '')
                       AND ISNULL(MyTable.Col4, '') = COALESCE(MyMaps.Col4, MyTable.Col4, '')
                    )

    FROM MyTable t
```

if it's for a small table, then it's ok. For large table, you might want to have a mapping table that defines how MyTable maps to MyMaps (rename it to MyTableLabel). You can calculate the mapping when you perform an insert or update operation.

alternatively, if MyMaps is known ahead of time i.e lookup table, you can define all combinations such as (a,b,c,d, label 1), (null, b,c,null, label2), (null, null,null, d, label3). This way, you can join without having to do COALESCE and ISNULL

Comment: I WISH I could do the mapping ahead of time - That definitely makes the most amount of sense! - Unfortunately, I can't since the business users want to be able to define rules pretty much dynamically via the Maps table. I'm just hoping there's a better mapping schema / implementation I could use than this one in total... Any ideas on it?

Comment: for now, just use a subquery like in my example. It'll use the 1st match. You should ask your business users on how to handle multiple matches. For ex) should the match that matched the most columns be used first? You an optimize the code as you get more requirements from your business users. For ex) they might give you a non-functional requirement that the query must return result under 2seconds

Comment: I guess people agree that your solution is the best - I was holding out and hoping for some kind of hail Mary here, but thank you so much for your attention and reply on this question!

Comment: Sorry John. It's hard to come up with any other solution without knowing more about your internal system i.e table schema and indexes, user requirements, and system process i.e how these tables are populated and from what systems. if you can reveal more info without violating your corporate policy, I'm sure everyone here will take another crack at it. Best of luck.